# Redirect serial console for telnet/ssh access to my linux box

Tags: c, linux

I have to redirect the serial console of a linux box for telnet and ssh access .
I am planning to write a c program which will accomplish this functionality .

According to my thoughts , I should write a c program which will call the ioctl calls to redirect the console while telnet/ssh access session . But I am not sure about the exact ioctl calls to achieve this . Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the existing programs that perform this?

Comment: Ignacio: Pick your favourite tools and write it up as an answer.